# Biztalk JSON Encoder String To Integer

Tags: json, biztalk, pipeline

I have a problem about JSON encoder. I've create send pipeline which include a JSON encoder. When my process worked JSON Send pipeline return response message to request side. But JSON encoder convert string value to integer if value is integer. For example please see below JSON.

```
{
    "BusIdentity": {
                "ErpId": 2075467
               },
    "Success": true,
    "ErrorMessages": [
    "Müşteri yaratıldı",
    "Başarılı"
    ]
}
```

In this example **ErpId** field have to be a  **"ErpId": "0002075467"** but pipeline convert 0002075467 value to 2075467.

Have you got an any idea for this issue?

[image]

Comment: is the type of the ErpId node an xs:string or an xs:int?

Comment: ErpId's type is xs:string

Comment: Where do you get this value ? i mean where and how do you get your values (ErpId for example) can you show us ?

Comment: Can you post your JSON schema?

Comment: After redeploying the application, above issue has been solved. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After redeploying the application issue has been solved.